How do I test an entity reference dropdown select field in functional tests?
Does anyone have any example or reference to test entity reference dropdown select field in functional tests?
I am trying to test a entity reference dropdown select(Taxonomy Field) field in Node Entity.
My Field Definition is as defined in the attached images below.



I tried the below combinations but none worked.
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

$page->selectFieldOption('field_feed_channel[0][target_id]', $this->channelTerm->label());
$page->selectFieldOption('field_feed_channel[0][target_id]', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->selectFieldOption('Channel Taxonomy Value', $this->channelTerm->label());
$page->selectFieldOption('Channel Taxonomy Value', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->selectFieldOption('edit-field-feed-channel', $this->channelTerm->label());
$page->selectFieldOption('field_feed_channel', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->fillField('Channel Taxonomy Value', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->fillField('Channel Taxonomy Value', $this->channelTerm->getName());
$page->fillField('field_feed_channel[target_id]', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->fillField('field_feed_channel[target_id]', $this->channelTerm->getName());

$page->pressButton('Save');



After multiple trail and errors the following code worked.
// Single value assigning to the field.
$page->selectFieldOption('field_associated_channels', $this->channelTerm->id());
$page->fillField('field_associated_channels', $this->channelTerm->id());    
$page->fillField('Channel Taxonomy Value', $this->channelTerm->id());


// Multiple value assigning to the field.
$page->selectFieldOption('field_associated_channels[]', $channel_term1->id());
$this->assertTrue($this->assertSession()->optionExists('field_associated_channels[]', $channel_term1->id())->isSelected());
$page->selectFieldOption('field_associated_channels[]', $channel_term2->id(), TRUE);
$page->selectFieldOption('field_associated_channels[]', $channel_term3->id(), TRUE);

